# Rename downloaded files with Wget -i

Tags: wget

I am trying to download bulk images from URL'S listed in text file.

The command I am using is

```
wget -i linksfile.txt
```

The url structure of images in linksfile.txt is like below

www.domainname.com/197507/1-foto-000.jpg?20180711125016
www.domainname.com/197507/2-foto-000.jpg?20180711125030
www.domainname.com/197507/3-foto-000.jpg?20180711125044
www.domainname.com/197507/4-foto-000.jpg?20180711125059

Download images are being saved with filenames as

1-foto-000.jpg?20180711125016
2-foto-000.jpg?20180711125030
3-foto-000.jpg?20180711125044
4-foto-000.jpg?20180711125059

How can I omit all the text after .jpg ? I want file names to be saved as

1-foto-000.jpg
2-foto-000.jpg
3-foto-000.jpg
4-foto-000.jpg

and If possible can filenames be saved as

197507-1-foto-000.jpg
197507-2-foto-000.jpg
197507-3-foto-000.jpg
197507-4-foto-000.jpg

197507 is the folder name where images are hosted on server

I read tutorials on file name changing, Most of them are focused on downloading single file and using wget -o to change file name,, Is there any way we  implement in above scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `--content-disposition` would do the trick.

Comment: wget -i linksfile.txt --content-disposition has solved the extension issue (y) thanks.

any idea how can I add FolderName before saved filename ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible with wget itself. You may try to write a shell script for creating the folders, cd'ing into them and execute wget in there. But that's more a dirty workaround.

Comment: I have found a way but it is not with code.

Download files in respective folders and mass rename them. This way we will have to rename files of each folder manually.